# python: I want to make a dictionary using two, two dimensional lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, zip

I want to make a single list with two dictionaries in it using two, two dimensional lists. Note that each element should have to be paired to the element of the second list.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
c = dict(zip(a,b))
```

is not working because list is not hash-able.
Then I need the out put as

```
 c = [{1:7, 2:8, 3:9}, {4:10, 5:11, 6:12}]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example output (what `c` should look like) to clarify?

Comment: You're trying to use `[1,2,3]` as a key.

Comment: Okay, C = [{1:7, 2:8, 3:9 }, {4:10, 5:11, 6:12} ]

Comment: No, I want to use the integers as keys, but the structure has to be just like the above

Comment: `c` is not a dictionary, it is a *list* so why do you think `dict` would return it?

Comment: Right, I have to edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like the following:

```py
c = [dict(zip(keys, vals)) for keys, vals in zip(a, b)]
```

Here we use a list comprehension to zip and cast to a dict for each inner list in the original lists `a` and `b`.

Alternatively, we could flatten out the comprehension further, to get:

```py
c = [{k: v for k, v in zip(keys, vals)} for keys, vals in zip(a, b)]
```

Both are equivalent, its just a matter of style.

Output:

```py
>>> print(c)
[{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9}, {4: 10, 5: 11, 6: 12}]
```

Comment: @TestDft glad to hear. Please consider accepting the answer (and possibly upvoting) if it resolves the issue